# Magento2.1.12: Removing <tr> <td> tags from subtotal block

Tags: magento2, cart, subtotal

Today, I'm facing very weird issue. We've a magento store developed on version 2.1.12. When I add product in the cart, the subtotal summary block at right side on cart page is not showing properly. It's disturbed due to removal of `<tr> <td>` tags from the block. It's only showing `<span>` tag. Please see this [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/jgjq19) . It should be wrapped with `<tr> <td>` tag like [this](http://prntscr.com/jgjqh1)

I've checked in the template file located at `Magento_Tax/template/checkout/summary/subtotal.phtml`

and it's showing `<tr> <td>`. The same file in **pub/static** folder is also proper. I'm really stuck into this and need immediate help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the full path of the html when page loads. May be you are checking the wrong file.

Comment: @Priyank Thanks for the reply. I checked again, but the file is correct. Seems to be server related issue.

Comment: Ok, it was server issue. After restarting the apache and pagespeed add-on, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer this question, although it has allready been answered in comments by @Deeps.

If you experience this issue, then it is possible related to Google Pagespeed addon.

Solved by either restarting or removing this addon completely.